# EmptyStackException Errors

Tags: java, stack

So I was trying to do a BalancedSymbols Class with the driver file provided to me by the professor. I got it to work in some cases, but in others I get EmptyStackException error.

Here is the prompt:

```
The BalancedSymbols class is a utility class that will be used to check if parentheses     (), brackets [], and braces {} are matched in a given string. The BalancedSymbols class object will never be instantiated. It has the following method:

public static String balancedSymbols(String lineToCheck)

The balancedSymbols method's argument is a string that can contain parenthesis, brackets, and braces. Other characters or numbers can appear before/after/between them.

If all symbols ({([) matched, then the method should return the string:

"Everything is matched!"

If there is a closing parenthesis, bracket, or brace that does not have its corresponding opening parenthesis, bracket, or brace,
then for the first such character, return a string with its position such as:

") at the position 15 does not match."

"] at the position 12 does not match."

OR

"} at the position 28 does not match."

The first character of the string is at position 0.

If there are no matching closing parenthesis, bracket, and/or brace when you reach the end of the string after checking each character, return a string notifying the last opening parenthesis, bracket, or brace that did not have its matching closing one as:

") is missing."

"] is missing."

OR

"} is missing."

Requirement:

You need to implement this method using a Stack from java.util package.

You can use the string "A" as a token for parentheses, "B" as a token for brackets, "C"    as a token for braces.

When an opening parenthesis is read, push the token "A", and when a closing parenthesis is read, pop the token "A" if available.
A similar operation can be done for others. Only if the stack is empty when you finish reading all characters of the string, you can confirm that everything was matched. Otherwise, the method needs to return an appropriate message stated above
```

Here is the driver file given to me:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment11
 {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
   {
   char input1;
   String inputInfo;
   String line = new String();

   printMenu();

   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
   BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(isr);

   do  // will ask for user input
    {
     System.out.println("What action would you like to perform?");
     line = stdin.readLine();
     input1 = line.charAt(0);
     input1 = Character.toUpperCase(input1);

     if (line.length() == 1)
      {
       // matches one of the case statements
       switch (input1)
        {
         case 'E':   //Enter String
           System.out.print("Please enter a string.\n");
           inputInfo = stdin.readLine().trim();
           System.out.println(BalancedSymbols.balancedSymbols(inputInfo));
           break;
         case 'Q':   //Quit
           break;
         case '?':   //Display Menu
           printMenu();
           break;
         default:
           System.out.print("Unknown action\n");
           break;
        }
      }
     else
      {
       System.out.print("Unknown action\n");
      }
    } while (input1 != 'Q' || line.length() != 1);
   }


  /** The method printMenu displays the menu to a user**/
  public static void printMenu()
   {
     System.out.print("Choice\t\tAction\n" +
                    "------\t\t------\n" +
                    "E\t\tEnter String\n" +
                    "Q\t\tQuit\n" +
                    "?\t\tDisplay Help\n\n");
  }
}
```

Here is what I coded:

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class BalancedSymbols
{
   private static final String OPEN = "([{";
  private static final String CLOSE = ")]}";

   public static String balancedSymbols(String lineToCheck)
   {
   Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
   boolean balanced = true;

   int index = 0;
   String curr = "";
   String top = "";
   char missedChar = ' ';
   while(balanced && index < lineToCheck.length())
   {
       curr = lineToCheck.substring(index, index + 1);

       if(OPEN.indexOf(curr) > -1)
       {
           stack.push(curr);

           missedChar = CLOSE.charAt(OPEN.indexOf(curr));
       }
       else if(CLOSE.indexOf(curr) > -1)
       {
           top = stack.pop();

           if(OPEN.indexOf(top) != CLOSE.indexOf(curr))
           {                      
               balanced = false;
               break;
           }

       }          

       index++;
   }  

   if(index > lineToCheck.length())
   {
       missedChar = CLOSE.charAt(OPEN.indexOf(stack.peek()));
   }

   if(balanced && stack.isEmpty())
   {
       return "Everything is matched!";
   }
   else if(index < lineToCheck.length())
   {
       return missedChar + " at the position " + index + " does not match.";      
   }
   else
   {
       return missedChar + " is missing.";
   }
   }

}
```

I'm able to pass some of the test cases when they match, but when I input something like "[[[[][][][][]]]]][[]][][][][]]]]" I get an EmptyStackException error, along with some other inputs.

In addition to that, other inputs give me the wrong type of bracket that's missing, such as saying a ')' is missing instead of a '}'.

I'm pretty new to writing stacks, so I appreciate any help with my code. This is also my first question so I apologize if it's long or hard to read.

Comment: Yes, it is long and hard to read.  Have you stepped through your code in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Here are hints on how to start:

1. no need for arraylist. You create a Stack object. Stack myStack = new Stack();
2. you need to use: push, pop, and peek methods
3. You need a while loop, read the first character from in the string (lineToCheck)

if it is an opening parenthesis push it into your stack, if the current character is closing parenthesis, check to see if the last one was an opening parenthesis (use peek method)

if it is pop else set your boolean to exit the loop and print the position where the character is not matching.

1. Now the same for bracket
2. same for brace
3. at the end if you reach the last character of the string and check to see if the stack is empty. if not, then a closing one is missing

I hope this helps!